# How can I convert a unicode value to it's representation?

Tags: java, scala, unicode, emoji

I'm sorry, I may have worded this question very poorly. Here is what I have

```
1f1e8-1f1f3
```

That represents a flag emoji. I can successfully convert a normal unicode value to it's emoji with this:

```
new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(e.unified.split("-").head, 16)))
```

But for the emojis that have dashes I can't. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I will gladly provide more information if it's needed. I honestly don't have the vocabulary or understanding of unicode values to properly articulate my issue.

What I need to do is this: Take a unicode value (ex. value from above) and turn it into a character, or string. Instead of the unicode value, I want what that value represents...I hope this is a little more helpful.

Comment: What class type is `e`?

Comment: e holds information for an emoji. The e.unified is pulling the unicode value out of that class. So the e.unified would be the 1f1e8-1f1f3. As you can see I'm only taking the first portion of that string up to the dash. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag emojis are made of **two** [regional indicator symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol). It was done this way to avoid political arguments: it's up to font designers to pick which country flags they want to support, Unicode itself is neutral.

Each regional indicator symbol has to be presented in Java as two surrogates.

So you just need to create your string from several parts:

```
new String(e.unified.split("-").flatMap{ codepoint => 
    Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(codepoint, 16))
})
```